# How many non-isomorphic semigroups are there of orders $2$ and $3$?

Tags: finite-semigroups

For order $2$, I have found 5. There are 16 maps from $\{a, b\} \times \{a, b\} \to\{a, b\}$. They form $10$ equivalence classes of non-isomorphic binary operations, $5$ of which are associative. Of these $2$ are monoids and $1$ is a group.They are

1. The group $ \mathrm Z/2 $
2. $\{ 0, 1\}$ with standard multiplication.
3. $\{a, b\}$ with $x \circ y = a$ for all $x$ and $y$ $=a$ or $b$
4. $\{a, b\}$ with $x \circ y = x$ for all $x$ and $y$ $=a$ or $b$
5. $\{a, b\}$ with $x \circ y = y$ for all $x$ and $y$ $=a$ or $b$

Is $5$ the correct number of semigroups for $n=2$ ?

How many semigroups are there for $n=3$ ? No proof is needed, but a reference would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reference is http://oeis.org/A027851

There are $5$ nonisomorphic semigroups of order $2,$ and $24$ of order $3.$

Answer (score 1):

Up to isomorphism *and anti-isomorphism*, there are 4 semigroups of order 2, and 18 of order 3. (An anti-isomorphism is essentially transposing the multiplication table, up to re-labeling; formally, an anti-isomorphism of semigroups is a bijection $\phi: S\rightarrow T$ where $\phi(s_1s_2)=\phi(s_2)\phi(s_1)$.)

Indeed, up to isomorphism and anti-isomorphism:
$$
\begin{array}{c|r}
\text{Size}&\text{Number of semigroups}\\
\hline
1& 1\\
2& 4\\
3& 18\\
4& 126\\
5& 1,160\\
6& 15,973\\
7& 836,021\\
8& 1,843,120,128\\
9& 52,989,400,714,478
\end{array}
$$
For a reference, you can find this table in the documentation for the [SmallSemi GAP package.](https://www.gap-system.org/Packages/smallsemi.html) (Like the Small Groups package, but for semigroups.)

Comment: In 1) i'm using addition mod 2 so the core of the Cayley Table looks like $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 & 1\\1 & 0\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$
. While in 2) I'm using multiplication so the corresponding table is  $\bigl( \begin{smallmatrix} 0 & 0\\0 & 1\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$

Comment: @bof $0$ is the identity and is its own inverse.

Comment: 2) is not a group $1$ is the identity and here $0$ has no inverse.

Comment: Okay, I understand. The issue was that the table I found is up to isomorphism and "anti-isomorphism" (this took me a while to work out!). I've edited this into my answer.

Comment: @StephenMeskin Sorry, by (1) I meant (2).

Comment: @Zach Fixed. Thanks.